# Showing/hiding HTML5 video player controls

Tags: html, css

So I have created custom buttons/icons for HTML5 video player. Problem is, that I would like to hide these buttons, except progress bar, when mouse is not pointed on the video.

I have used css :hover, but it only shows buttons when I am directly at them, but I would like to have effect that they show up when mouse is on video container, tho progress bar should remain.

```
#video-controls {
  opacity: 0;
}

#video-controls:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

Also, does anyone have idea how to move progress bar down to bottom when buttons aren't showing?

```
<div id="video_container">
    <video id="video">
        <source src="video_new.mp4" type="video/mp4">
        <source src="video_new.ogg" type="video/ogg">
    </video>
  <div id="video-controls">
    <button type="button" id="play-pause"><input type="image" src="icons/play.png" alt="play button icon"></button>

    <button type="button" id="mute"><input type="image" src="icons/volume_on.png" alt="volume ON icon"></button>
    <button type="button" id="full-screen"><input type="image" src="icons/fullscreen.png" alt="fullscreen button icon"></button>
    <div><span id="currentTime">00:00</span></div><div id="duration"><span>00:00</span></div>
    </div>
 <progress id="progress" value="0">
   <span id="progress-bar"></span>
 </progress>
</div>
```

Comment: CSS alone might not help, you'll need JS

Comment: Instead of `:hover` on `#video-controls` make it on `#video_container`. So `#video_container:hover #video-controls { opacity: 1; }`.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `:hover` on `#video-controls` make it on `#video_container`.

So try this:

```css
#video_container:hover #video-controls { 
  opacity: 1; 
}
```

Here is an example: https://jsfiddle.net/4h9jkrLz/1/

Comment: Hm, seems not to work with me, although I have exact code.

Comment: @K.Leins could it be working but your video object is hiding it? You may try to add a `z-index` of `999` to `#video-controls` since it is absolutely positioned.